# JavaScript gives me [object HTMLTableCellElement] instead of the content of the cell

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

HTML:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

script:

```
  var zahlen = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var ma = zahlen[0];

for(var i = 1; i <= zahlen.length; i++)
{
   if(ma > zahlen[i])
    ma = zahlen[i];   
}
document.writeln(ma);
```

I want that "ma" gives me the highest number of the  tags, written on screen, which must be the 5 but instead it comes: [object HTMLTableCellElement], I don't get it, please help me and explain me how it works.

Comment: The list returned from `getElementsByTagName()` is a list of DOM element references. If you want the *content* of an element, you need to get that from the API for that element type, probably the `.textContent` property of each element.

Comment: Your loop should probably start and `0` and you should use `<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way to get the inner content of `<td>` using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) becasue for your case it is returning the html element like `<td>1</td>` while you use `zahlen[0]`.

**N.B**: Also cache the variable inside loop like `zah = zahlen[i].innerHTML` and use `zah` in the condition. Hope this helps :)

```js
var zahlen = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var ma = zahlen[0].innerHTML;

for (var i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++) {
      zah = zahlen[i].innerHTML;
      if (ma < zah) ma = zah;    
}
document.writeln(ma);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But this just gets me the 1 instead of the 5

Comment: But Why do I need: zahlen[i] && typeof zahlen[i].innderHTML != undefined

Comment: to fix the `undefined` issue, if you want to escape that condition then you've use this `var i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++`, See my **edit.** I've remove the `=` on `i<= zahlen.length`. Hope you understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLTableCellElement` is the type of object that the `zalen` `NodeList` have instances of. To get the content of a `HTMLTableCellElement` you can use its `innerText` property:

```
for ... {
  ma = zahlen[i].innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
 <tr id="nesto">
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</body>
<script>
  var zahlen = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var ma = zahlen[0].innerHTML;
for(var i = 1; i <= zahlen.length-1; i++)
{
  if(ma < zahlen[i].innerHTML)
       ma = zahlen[i].innerHTML;  
}
document.writeln(ma);
</script>
</html>
```

The otput was an html code, you have to use the property **innerHTML** to get the content of the td elements. This code works fine